# Received double rep for one upvote

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I appear to have received +20 rep for a single upvote that occurred for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9215507/328397).

The rep appears as two +10 entries at the same date and time (18:22) for the same answer.

There were no downvotes:

[image: a]

Comment: Why did you submit two answers instead of improving one? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two entries are for [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code/9215507#9215507) [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code/5724712#5724712) answers on the same question.

It looks like someone(s) up voted [most of/all the answers and the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/333664/timeline) yesterday.

Comment: Wow I had no idea the "timeline" MVC route existed!

Comment: It's deprecated in its current form, but still a bit useful every now and then.